# Starting a sentence with a preposition

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, syntax

Recently I've heard someone say "Off I go." At first it sounded a bit strange, then I've realized maybe it could be a saying. Or maybe not. So here it is my question: Are there any other sentences, or can I form sentences where it is allowed to start with a preposition?

Comment: _Off to work I go._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly begin a sentence with a preposition. In your example (see, I've just done it), *off* is an adverb rather than a preposition, but you can still begin a sentence with it. Similar examples are *In I go, On I go, Out I go* and *Up I go*.

Comment: +1 However, putting the adverb that specifies the direction of *go* first is idiomatic and not exactly regular. That is, it is the most common word order in these expressions, but it is unusual elsewhere; I would call it a form of inversion.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can. Like I just did. Up until now, all my sentences have started with prepositions.  (That last sentence started with two of them.)

In your question (and there's another one), where you say:

> At first it sounded a bit strange, then I've realized maybe it could be a saying.

You start off a sentence with a preposition, so I guess even though you didn't know if it could be done you knew you could do it.  :)

There's an incomplete, but useful list of prepositions [here](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-list.htm). If you look through it, you'll find a lot of them will happily sit at the front of a sentence.

Comment: I sure did, oddly I haven't realized that before. But in my opinion it's more common finding 'at' at the beginning of a sentence rather than 'off'. That 'off' in particular was unsettling for me. Thank you for your answer and of course your list.

Comment: I think "up" was an adverb in the "up until".